# TypeError: _init_() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

I am testing a Android UI using monkeyrunner. I am successful in starting a activity using MonkeyRunner using startActivity(component). But now I want to click a Button on my UI named 'Example' using following code:

> device.startActivity(component=runComponent)
>
> vc=ViewClient(device)
>
> vc.dump()

When I run this python script, upon reaching this line my script ends with error

> vc=ViewClient(device)
>
> TypeError: _*init*() takes at least 3 arguments (2 Given)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

A view with name **Entry** can be pressed  using following line in monkey runner

```
vc=ViewClient.findViewWithText('Entry')
vc.touch()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ViewClient's **init** signature and epydoc:

```
def __init__(self, device, serialno, adb=None, autodump=True, localport=VIEW_SERVER_PORT, remoteport=VIEW_SERVER_PORT, startviewserver=True):
    '''
    Constructor

    @type device: MonkeyDevice
    @param device: The device running the C{View server} to which this client will connect
    @type serialno: str
    @param serialno: the serial number of the device or emulator to connect to
    @type adb: str
    @param adb: the path of the C{adb} executable or None and C{ViewClient} will try to find it
    @type autodump: boolean
    @param autodump: whether an automatic dump is performed at the end of this constructor
    @type localport: int
    @param localport: the local port used in the redirection
    @type remoteport: int
    @param remoteport: the remote port used to start the C{ViewServer} in the device or
                       emulator
    @type startviewserverparam: boolean
    @param startviewserverparam: Whether to start the B{global} ViewServer
    '''
```

As you can see, **init** takes at least 2 arguments: `device` and `serialno`.
All the other arguments are optional.
In most of the cases these arguments are obtained from ViewClient.connectToDevice():

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(component=component)
time.sleep(3)
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
```

**IMPORTANT:**
You should connect to your device only once. You only need `MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection` or `AndroidViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit` not *BOTH*!

Comment: After applying the above changes, my activity is not starting and command prompt is static showing 
121216 15:33:29.016:I [MainThread] [com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager] Monkey Command: wake.
There is no furthur response

Comment: May be a Chimpchat bug. Try restarting adb: adb kill-server